# Andriod Studio Build is not showing "make project " apk

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, signed-apk

I just completed working on my first application just frontend nothing connected with backend or database before connecting with a backend I need to show the basic functionality to my leads. It's a react-native project in Visual Studio after researching and seeing so many videos I find that I can release a Signed Akk through Andriod Studio and open the project by this method :
Clicked on Android Studio > Open Existing project then its load itself and was done .. but the main issue is when I click on the **Build** Option but there I can't find the "Generate Apk Option " can everyone help me ... that where the issue is?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGd30.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

- You should open the android folder from Android Studio, no all react-native project.
- android folder exists if you have created bare  workflow project, example with npx react-native init AwesomeProject.
- If you project has been created with expo, you need eject.